# Laravel hasMany with multiple constraints

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have query that I run on my `ServiceController`

```
return Service::with('contacts', 'locations.datetimes')->find($service->id);
```

This works great perfectly, but I need to change it. The relationships are defined as follows:

```
class Service extends Model
{
  public function locations()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Service_location', 'service_location_service');
  }
}

class Service_location extends Model
{
  public function datetimes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Service_detail');
  }
}
```

I need a second constraint on the datetimes where I need the relationship to be along the lines of

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Service_detail')->where('service_id', $service->id);
```

The problem is I can't find a way to pass through the $service_id. How do you handle two constraints on a hasMany relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let try this. Change Service_location to this

```
 class Service_location extends Model
 {
      public function datetimes()
      {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Service_detail');
      }

      public function scopeServiceId($query)
      {
          return $query->where('service_id', $service->id);
      }
}
```

Now your query will be

```
 Service::with(['contacts', 'locations.datetimes' =>function($q) use($serviceId){
     $q->serviceId($serviceId);
 }])->find($service->id);
```

There is no way to pass argument to a relationship function. If you do its highly likely that you will run into the N+1 query problem.